# Java programming object terminology

Tags: programming-languages, java, object-oriented

Say there is a class called `Person`. Then in the following expression :

`Person human = new Person()`

Which is the "reference" and which is the "object"?

`human` should be the reference since it's not an actual object, it simply points to an object. On the other side, `new Person()` truly is the actual object. I've seen these terms used vice versa and I was wondering what's the actual naming?

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. What does *The Java Language Specification* specify for *the `new` operator*? Does it specify `the "object"` to appear in a reference assignment? (consider tagging [tag:terminology])

Comment: Hi, I believe this is a programming question. Programming questions should be asked on stackoverflow.com, not on cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score -2):

Person is a class and human is an object the most important key point about object is it points towards feilds and  methods but here you will see in braces you have passed nothing means class Person have no parametrized constructor but have a default one

Thanks bro if you will find any difficulty while doing java i am here for your help so free to ask